# How to pass testng parameters in maven multi modules

Tags: maven, testng, maven-module

I have maven project with 4 modules
Project

```
   --->module 1
     |
     --->WebDriver setUp

   --->module 2
     |
     ----> testng.xml
```

How can I get in setUp() parameters from testng.xml file ?

Comment: It looks like an integration test which should be handled into a single separate module like `module-it` which contains the whole configuration for the integration tests.

Comment: @khmarbaise module 1 is a common module that contains configuration files, but it does not work as well

Comment: I want to run cross browser my tests that are under module 2, but webdriver setup is common to all modules, so I want to send different parameters from all module